# What happens when there is no variation within a category in panel data?

Tags: regression, fixed-effects-model

I have a dataset with multiple rows per individual. Each row represents the number of items sold by an employee on a given day. Suppose I have thousands of employees, and each of them has roughly five records each. Likewise, all employees are assigned to a branch (i.e., branches group multiple employees).

For example, the data for branch `01` would look as follows:

| employee_id | day | branch_id | employees_in_branch | items_sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | branch_01 | 7 | 12 |
| 1234 | 2 | branch_01 | 7 | 0 |
| 1234 | 3 | branch_01 | 7 | 4 |
| 1234 | 4 | branch_01 | 7 | 22 |
| 1234 | 5 | branch_01 | 7 | 15 |
| 5678 | 1 | branch_01 | 7 | 2 |
| 5678 | 2 | branch_01 | 7 | 3 |
| 5678 | 3 | branch_01 | 7 | 7 |
| 5678 | 4 | branch_01 | 7 | 2 |
| 5678 | 5 | branch_01 | 7 | 14 |

The number of employees in each branch does vary from one branch to another. However, there is no variation in the column `employees_in_branch` **within** each branch.

What would happen if I were to run a fixed effects model and include `employees_in_branch` as an independent variable?

$$
E(Y|X) = g(\text{branch_id}, \text{employees_in_branch})
$$

I know neither column is a linear combination of the other. However, `employees_in_branch` seems like a variable that the fixed effect coefficient could absorb, so I am wondering if adding `employees_in_branch` would be redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't; a fixed-effects model cannot include cluster-level covariates (in your case, anything that is constant within each store).

More generally, your data set has a hierarchical structure that is ideal for a multilevel model, as you presumably expect to have both within-employee and within-store correlation. If $y_{ijk}$ is the number of items sold in day $i$ by employee $j$ in store $k$, your model would be something like
$$
y_{ijk} = \boldsymbol{\beta}'\mathbf{x}_{ijk} +  u_{jk} + v_k + \varepsilon_{ijk}
$$
where $u_{jk}$ and $v_k$ are, respectively, the random effects associated with the employee and the store. The matrix $\mathbf{x}_{ijk}$ can contain explanatory variables be defined at any of the levels (day, employee, or store).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot include either variable since there is no variation in those covariates within each employee. When you perform the demeaning/within transformation, they will drop out of the model. They get absorbed into the fixed effect but are not separately identified. You can only include covariates that vary across time for each employee.

Here's a demonstration:

```
. webuse pig, clear
(Longitudinal analysis of pig weights)

. xtset id week

Panel variable: id (strongly balanced)
 Time variable: week, 1 to 9
         Delta: 1 unit

. xtdescribe

      id:  1, 2, ..., 48                                     n =         48
    week:  1, 2, ..., 9                                      T =          9
           Delta(week) = 1 unit
           Span(week)  = 9 periods
           (id*week uniquely identifies each observation)

Distribution of T_i:   min      5%     25%       50%       75%     95%     max
                         9       9       9         9         9       9       9

     Freq.  Percent    Cum. |  Pattern
 ---------------------------+-----------
       48    100.00  100.00 |  111111111
 ---------------------------+-----------
       48    100.00         |  XXXXXXXXX

. gen group_id = inrange(id,1,15)

. egen pigs_in_grp = nvals(id), by(group_id)

. xtsum

Variable         |      Mean   Std. dev.       Min        Max |    Observations
-----------------+--------------------------------------------+----------------
id       overall |      24.5   13.86946          1         48 |     N =     432
         between |                   14          1         48 |     n =      48
         within  |                    0       24.5       24.5 |     T =       9
                 |                                            |
week     overall |         5   2.584983          1          9 |     N =     432
         between |                    0          5          5 |     n =      48
         within  |             2.584983          1          9 |     T =       9
                 |                                            |
weight   overall |  50.40509   16.64113         20         88 |     N =     432
         between |             3.953498         43   59.77778 |     n =      48
         within  |             16.17366   20.12731   83.40509 |     T =       9
                 |                                            |
group_id overall |     .3125   .4640498          0          1 |     N =     432
         between |             .4684174          0          1 |     n =      48
         within  |                    0      .3125      .3125 |     T =       9
                 |                                            |
pigs_i~p overall |    27.375   8.352897         15         33 |     N =     432
         between |             8.431514         15         33 |     n =      48
         within  |                    0     27.375     27.375 |     T =       9

. xtreg weight i.week i.group_id c.pigs_in_grp, fe
note: 1.group_id omitted because of collinearity.
note: pigs_in_grp omitted because of collinearity.

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs     =        432
Group variable: id                              Number of groups  =         48

R-squared:                                      Obs per group:
     Within  = 0.9857                                         min =          9
     Between = 0.0000                                         avg =        9.0
     Overall = 0.9311                                         max =          9

                                                F(8,376)          =    3232.74
corr(u_i, Xb) = 0.0000                          Prob > F          =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      weight | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        week |
          2  |   6.760417   .4231323    15.98   0.000     5.928414    7.592419
          3  |   13.84375   .4231323    32.72   0.000     13.01175    14.67575
          4  |     19.375   .4231323    45.79   0.000       18.543      20.207
          5  |   25.13542   .4231323    59.40   0.000     24.30341    25.96742
          6  |   31.42708   .4231323    74.27   0.000     30.59508    32.25909
          7  |    37.4375   .4231323    88.48   0.000      36.6055     38.2695
          8  |   44.28125   .4231323   104.65   0.000     43.44925    45.11325
          9  |   50.19792   .4231323   118.63   0.000     49.36591    51.02992
             |
  1.group_id |          0  (omitted)
 pigs_in_grp |          0  (omitted)
       _cons |   25.02083   .2991997    83.63   0.000     24.43252    25.60915
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  3.9534984
     sigma_e |  2.0729165
         rho |  .78436522   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F test that all u_i=0: F(47, 376) = 32.74                    Prob > F = 0.0000
```

The collinearity warnings above alert you to the problem and are omitted in the output.

Comment: Jesus, is that stata? D: Just kidding. Thank you for your response! When you say I cannot include either variable, how come I cannot include `branch_id`? Obviously, I would one-hot encode each branch and drop one level (or use `branch_id` as a second index) to tell python those are my fixed effects.

Comment: It is Stata, but exact collinearity is a math fact, so the software does not matter. The branch does not vary for each employee, so demeaning always removes the branch dummy. In your example, both employees work at branch 1, so the average of the branch 1 dummy is also 1 for each of them them, and 1-1=0. For those who work in other branches, the average of branch 1 dummy is 0, so 0-0 is 0. This means the demeaned branch 1 dummy is always zero for everyone. You could only include branch FEs if employees work at multiple branches.